# Regex pattern Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Task in kotlinlang:
Using month variable rewrite this pattern in such a way that it matches the date in format 13 JUN 1992 (two digits, a whitespace, a month abbreviation, a whitespace, four digits).

Answer is: 
`val month = "(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)"
fun getPattern(): String = """\d{2} ${month} \d{4}"""`
I can't understand `${month}`. How it works?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`${month}` is equal to `(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)`

So the String `"""\d{2} ${month} \d{4}"""` is actually expanded to

`"""\d{2} (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) \d{4}"""`

This a regex that captures a pair of numbers, followed by a space, then one of the values `JAN, FEB... DEC`, followed by another space and four more digits.
So Strings like `04 APR 1234` match the regex.

Comment: it's like check contains val month string FEB for example?

Comment: but why val month in that format "(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)"?

Comment: it also may be (JAN,FEB,MAR)?

Comment: To match `JAN` **or** `FEB` **or** `MAR` the pattern needs to be `(JAN|FEB|MAR)`. You might want to try reading about `or (|)` in regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: The pattern `a(b|c)d` matches `abd` and `acd`. It doesn't match the string `abcd`

Comment: I get it! Thank you!)

Answer (score 2):

Some addition to answer above!

```
 val month = "(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)"

    fun getPattern() = """\d{2}\ ${month}\ \d{4}"""

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println("11 FEB 1954".matches(getPattern().toRegex()))}
```